# Wordpress meta_query how to use "like" comparison on meta_key

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-key, meta-query

I have to get posts having a particular meta value for a `dynamic meta key`.

The `meta key` values will be:

- _project_global_1_trend_link
- _project_global_2_trend_link
- etc...

The common text in meta key is `trend_link`. So I need to add `like operator` for `meta key`.

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
            'numberposts'   => -1,
            'post_type'     => 'projects',
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                   'key'     => 'trend_link',
                   'value'   => 10,
                   'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
             )
        ));
```

By using this code I can apply `like operator` on `meta_value`.

> But I need to apply `like operator` on `meta_key`.

Is there any way to apply `like operator` on `meta_key`.

Please help !!

Answer (score 5):

For this situation you can use a parameter "compare_key"

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
            'numberposts'   => -1,
            'post_type'     => 'projects',
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                   'key'     => 'trend_link',
                   'compare_key' => 'LIKE',
                   'value'   => 10,
                   'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
             )
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

If i'm correct you can add a dollar sign to the meta key for dynamic keys!

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
        'numberposts'   => -1,
        'post_type'     => 'projects',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
               'key'     => '_project_global_%_trend_link',
               'value'   => 10,
               'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
         )
    ));
```